# Dynamic tabs pointing to separate JSPs (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm following [this w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h).

When each tab is clicked , respective DIV element is loaded.
I am trying to call separate jsp file for each tab, by changing the href value but help less. its breaking the Tab active status.

Any help?

[My code](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26166/)

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>HOME</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 1</h3>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 2</h3>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 3</h3>
            <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: Where is your code calling JSP files?

Comment: Sample is added in jsfiddle

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see what is going wrong in your fiddle... :/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26169

Comment: In the jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26169 i am trying give links for each tab, which is not working